# Easy way to integrate Jasmine JavaScript unit testing with TFS Build CI

Tags: javascript, build, tfs, jasmine

I've been writing JavaScript unit tests using Jasmine. However, those tests run inside a browser, not as part of MSTest.

I want my TFS Continuous Integration builds to break when a JavaScript unit test fails. I know there is a solution for this in Visual Studio 2012, but I'm on 2010 (and will be for a long time in the future probably).

Is there an easy way to integrate Jasmine based JavaScript unit tests with TFS Build?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Chutzpah](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah) test runner enables you to run your QUnit and Jasmine JavaScript unit tests from the command line or Visual Studio.

Therefore you should be able to integrate it into your TFS build via the InvokeProcess activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use nodejs + jasmine-node, but you can also look at http://phantomjs.org/ with a junit reporter.  Jasmine-node provides a junit reporter with the --junitreport output.  You might also look at the TFS Build Extensions (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d7c8577-54b8-47ce-82a5-8649f579dcb6/view/Discussions/) and the activities in there.  It includes a xml transform for JUnit to TRX (test results xml) which can be pushed into TFS.